# Extra columns in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Excel 2013 and am breaking down customer records by ethnicity and the number of deps (children) they have:

[image: Pivot Table]

I want to add additional columns to look at how many of each category have more than 2 children (you can see these in the image I have tried to add 3 cols manually).

Column N was OK as it let me sum the values in cols E to L, but I want to display the % in col O and this is not working because when I drag it down it behaves weirdly.

I think there must be a way in the pivot able itself to add these columns but I don't know how, can anyone advise?

Comment: What formula do you have in column `O` currently?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0IxepT0FbEFd3UtWU9zYTBacTA/view?usp=sharing

=N5/GETPIVOTDATA("claim_id",$A$3,"ethnicity","Any Other")

Comment: but dragging this down does not work properly?

Comment: In your source data table, you must write the formulas for the data you want to capture.  From there you can bring that "new" column to the pivot table.  This is the only way I know of to make calculated pivot table columns work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the cell you want to divide by, type it in so it reads (as an example):

> =N5/M5

Another option is to use:

> =N5/GETPIVOTDATA("claim_id",$A$3,"ethnicity",A5)

This happens because the reference of the cell you are dividing by does not change when you roll down the formula if that cell is in a pivot table. Instead, you have edit the GETPIVOTDATA() formula so that the reference is updated for every cell. That is why I changed the part where it said "Any Other" to reference the cell that contains that data.